# how to perform calculation by two factors

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the customer's satisfaction level for each employee each day, my data look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
        rep(seq(
                from=as.Date("2012-1-1",tz="UTC"),
                to=as.Date("2012-1-30",tz="UTC"),by="day"),50),
        as.factor(c(rep("A",300),rep("B",300),rep("C",300), rep("D",300),rep("E",300))),
        sample(c(1:5), 1500, replace = TRUE))
colnames(df)<-c("time", "staff_NO.", "rating")

df
```

the satisfaction level for each employee is (number of "5" and "4"rating/total number of ratings).

I know how to calculate the satisfaction level for each employee in general,,, ***I don't know how to do this using group_by function, if anyone knows, let me know !!!!!!!***

```
staffname<-unique(df$staff_NO.)
satisfied<-c()
for(k in 1: length(staffname)){ 
        print(satisfied[k]<-sum(df$staff_NO.==staffname[k]& (df$rating=="4"|df$rating=="5")) 
                /sum(df$staff_NO.==staffname[k]))
}
```

but I had problem adding time variable into it, meaning I don't know how to calculate the satisfaction level for each employee each day, can anyone help?

```
##this is what I ve tried....

day<-unique(df$time)
staffname<-unique(df$staff_NO.)
satisfied<-c()

for (j in 1: length(day)){
        for(k in 1: length(staffname)){ 
             print(sum(df$staff_NO.==staffname[k]& df$time==day[j]&(df$rating=="4"|df$rating=="5")) 
                /sum(df$staff_NO.==staffname[k]))& df$time==day[j]..
 *I want to save the result as a dataframe containing date, staff NO., and satisfaction level.*
```

Comment: are you are looking for a binary output for daily satisfaction given you have only one satisfaction level measured each day?

Comment: In your example, I only see one `rating` for each unique employee-day combination (assuming `staff_NO.` is an employee) unless I'm missing something. I suspect it might be easier for you to meet your objective using `dplyr` and grouping your dataframe by employee and day. For your example, please edit your question and provide what your desired output should look like to clarify (at least a few examples).

Comment: dude, Thanks for your kind reminder!!!I edited my dataframe just now....I am okay with grouping the dataframe by two varaibles and then calculate mean or something.. but I have no idea how to calculate satisfaction level based on the grouping, can you help me with that?